# Is it possible to grow cactus?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have about 3 or 4 cactus blocks that I found during an excursion, but it was really far from my base and there wasn't a lot of it.  Instead of making another long excursion just to search for more cactus, is it possible to plant what little I have in such a way that it will grow more cactus blocks for me to harvest?

If so, what is required for cactus to grow?  I know trees only need light.  Wheat needs water within 4 blocks and light, and reeds need water adjacent to them.  What are the requirements for cactus?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cactus must be placed in sand, and not adjacent to another block. Diagonally adjacent is okay.

It will grow even in complete darkness, and does not need water.

Comment: Catcus grows fully (three blocks height) in roughly one gameday.

Comment: Are there any other requirements?  Water, light, etc.?

Comment: It's also worth noting that any snow on top of the cactus will halt its growth, so put a roof over it or a heat source nearby if you're in a wintery area.

Comment: @Strix: water is not required and moonlight is enough.

Comment: Just tested it, and cactus does not need light to grow. Likewise with sugar cane, although sugar cane requires adjacent water.